# How to get names of files, which have changed from the last merge to master?

Tags: git, git-diff

```
A---B---C---D---H     (master)
     \ /   /
      E---F---G   (test)
```

**"X---Y" means that there can be several commits between X and Y**

The HEAD is in G

I'd like to get names of files which have changed from the merge F->D to the commit G

I use this, but it returns all the files that have changed from the E commit

```
git diff --name-only master...HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: now that the question is different**, let's re-draw the graph like this:

```
A---B---C---D--o--o--...--o--H   <-- master
     \ /   /
      E---F--o--...--o--G        <-- test
```

That is, `H^` or `master^` is some "uninteresting" commit, and we would have to find the number for `H~some-number` to name commit `D`.  If there are three extra commits in the `D--o--o--o--H` chain, it's `master~4`, for instance.  But we don't want to have to count.

Commit `F` is easy to find: it's the *merge base* of `master` and `test`.  Running `git merge-base master test` spits out the hash ID of commit `F`.  That's in effect what `git diff` does when we use `master...test`: it finds the merge base of the two commits, i.e., commit `F`.

We still want to compare commit `F` to commit `D`.  But we must find a *name* that represents commit `D`.  One sort-of-easy way, but not really that easy, to find `D` is to use a graphical log-viewer such as `git log --graph --oneline master test` or `gitk master test` and eyeball the graph, looking for commit `D`.  Once we find it, we can cut-and-paste the raw ID for commit `D`.

There is a programmatic way to find it, though.  Note that `D` is the *next commit in the direction of `master`*.<sup>1</sup>  Once we have the ID of `F`, we can take the entire set of commits reachable from `master` but not reachable from `F`, e.g., with:

```
git rev-list master ^F    # or, equivalently, F..master
```

The `^F` removes commits `F`, `E`, `B`, and `A` from our drawing.  Since we start from `master` and work backwards, we also never see commit `G`, nor any of the uninteresting commits before `G` and after `F`.  So this leaves us with this, where I leave commit `F` in brackets so that we can see where it is:

```
C---D--o--o--...--o--H   <-- master
[  / ]
[ F  ]
```

(Ideally we would draw `F` in greyed-out, or red color, or something, but I can't do that in a StackOverflow posting.)

What we want now, when using `git rev-list`, is the `--ancestry-path` option.  The `--ancestry-path` constraint instructs `git rev-list` to *discard*, from the output, *any commit that is not a descendant of all our explicitly-excluded commits*.  Our one explicitly-excluded commit is, of course, `F`.  So this discards commit `C`, which is not a *descendant* of `F`.  That leaves:

```
    D--o--o--...--o--H
```

and the first commit in this list—which of course `git rev-list` does not *print* first—is `D`.  The list actually comes out in reverse date order by default, and since `D` is the *oldest*, it generally comes out *last*.  (We really should add `--topo-order` here, to guarantee that `git rev-list` does not sort the commits by date order and hence shuffle `D` somewhere into the middle of the list, instead of at the end.)

#### Thus, the solution

Programmatically, we first find commit `F` using `git merge-base`.  Then we find commit `D` using `git rev-list` and `tail`.  (It's tempting to try to use `--reverse -n 1`, but that does not work.)  So:

```
mbase=$(git merge-base test master)
next=$(git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path ${mbase}..master | tail -1)
```

and then we can:

```
git diff $diff_flags $mbase $next
```

(set `diff_flags` to `--name-only` or `--name-status` as desired).

#### Alternatively...

There's a much easier way to find `D`, *provided that there are no other merges into master*.  We can simply use `git rev-list --merges -n 1 master` to find the most recent merge commit reachable from `master`.  In fact, when you're doing the kind of thing you are doing here, it's pretty common to *start* by looking for merges, and then `git diff` the merges' parents with the merge commits.  When working that way, just use `git log` or `git rev-list` with `--merges` to find the merge commit IDs, then use the `^2` suffix notation to find the predecessor merged-in commit:

```
merge=$(git rev-list --topo-order --merges -n 1 master)
git diff $diff_flags ${merge}^2 $merge
```

and you're done.

Note that we neither know nor care that `D^2` is on branch `test`, in this case; if we do want to know, we can use:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor ${merge}^2 test
```

to see if `${merge}^2` is an ancestor of commit `G`.  We can look for more merges if we want to find one specifically from `test` (but if we are doing that we might want to go back to the `--ancestry-path` method).

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible to create a graph where there is more than one such commit.  In that case, you must do more work, probably doing manual diffs.

---

#### Previous answer

Let's start with this: `git diff` compares two commits.<sup>1</sup>  The three-dot notation, which usually means "symmetric difference", has a different, and special, meaning in `git diff`: it finds the *merge base* of the two named commits.  Based on your drawing, the merge base of `master` (commit `D`) and `HEAD` (commit `G`) is commit `F`, not commit `E`.  The diff then compares that commit with the commit named on the right, so this should diff `F` vs `G`.

To diff commit `F` vs commit `D`, name those two commits.  There are many ways to do that, but it looks like `master` is the easiest way to name commit `D` (since `master` points directly to it) and `test^` or `test~1` is the easiest way to name commit `F` (since `test` points to commit `G` and the first parent of `G` is `F`).  Hence:

```
git diff test^ master
```

would do it in this case.  Use `--name-only` or `--name-status` to get just the names (and optionally, the `M` or `A` or `D` etc status-es), as you have been doing.

Whenever you have a merge commit like commit `D`, you can name its two parents using the `^` notation.  Hence, since `master` names commit `D`, `master^1` names the first parent (i.e., commit `C`) and `master^2` names the second parent (i.e., commit `F`).  So:

```
git diff master^2 master
```

would also compare commit `F` vs commit `D`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, one commit and the current work-tree; or one commit and the current index; or the index and the work-tree, etc.  In this case, though, you are picking which two commits to compare.

Comment: I am sorry, i did not formulate the question right, the question updated

Comment: i understood that i should compare not merge, but commit.But i don't understand the process of merging and what commits are changing during it. Nevertheless, you understand my question – PolyProgrammist 8 mins ago @torek

Comment: yeah, that's what i wanted to ask. Thank you very much, i'll test it later. @torek